# Refresh filter after leaving page and reload state to show the whole list when back to filtered page

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have a card on which am clicking to be redirected to a list page, where am applying a filter according to an id that am passing as an argument in the route here's the card :

```
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        redirectLinkNotif(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 2),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 2,
          color: kcolorbgnotif,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: const BorderSide(color: kcolorbordernotif, width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0),
                      child: const IconNotif(),
                    ),
                    ItemMessageNotification(
                        text: removeAllHtmlTags(localNotification!.message)),
                    if (!localNotification!.isRead) const IconReadNotif(),
                    if (localNotification!.isRead)
                      ItemDateNotif(
                        dateCreatedAt: localNotification!.createdAt,
                      )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
    RegExp exp = RegExp(r"<[^>]*>", multiLine: true, caseSensitive: true);

    return htmlText.replaceAll(exp, '');
  }

  void redirectLinkNotif(BuildContext context) {
    if (localNotification!.topic == "QRQC_CREATION") {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return BottomNavBar(
              index: 0,
              indexTab: 1,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    } else if (localNotification!.topic == "AUDIT_ASSIGNMENT") {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/audit',
          arguments: localNotification!.ordinalId ?? 0);

      print(localNotification!.ordinalId);
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return BottomNavBar(
              index: 4,
              indexTab: 0,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the list page :

```
class _AuditListBodyState extends State<AuditListBody> {
  Future? myFuture;
  List<AuditModel> listAudit = [];
  final fieldText = TextEditingController();
  String value = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fieldText.addListener(
      () {
        setState(() {
          value = fieldText.text;
        });
      },
    );

    myFuture = fetchData();
    // fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() async {
    listAudit = await Provider.of<AuditViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAllAudits();
    return listAudit;
  }

  void clearText() {
    fieldText.clear();
    setState(() {
      value = "";
    });
    Provider.of<AuditViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .changeSearchString(value);
  }

  String ordinalID = '';
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    if (args != null) {
      int ordId = 0;
      ordId = args as int;
      ordinalID = ordId.toString();
      fieldText.text = ordinalID;
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Provider.of<AuditViewModel>(context, listen: false)
            .changeSearchString(ordinalID);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<AuditModel> results = [];
    SizeConfig.init(context);
    return Consumer<AuditViewModel>(
        builder: ((context, value, child) => Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/deepnBg.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: SearchBarView(
                      clearText: clearText,
                      textController: fieldText,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        Provider.of<AuditViewModel>(context, listen: false)
                            .changeSearchString(value);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: myFuture,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                            case ConnectionState.none:
                            case ConnectionState.waiting:
                              return const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            default:
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (value.myList!.isEmpty)
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
                                    child: NoDataView(
                                      message:
                                          "Vous n'avez aucun audit à afficher",
                                    ),
                                  );
                                else
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: value.myList!.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return Stack(
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: CardAuditView(
                                                  auditModel:
                                                      value.myList![index]),
                                            ),
                                            Positioned(
                                                top: 0,
                                                right: 0,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    StatusBarAudit(
                                                      auditModel:
                                                          value.myList![index],
                                                    ),
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      width: 20,
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                )),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                              }
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                print(snapshot.error.toString());
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                      "Un problème est survenu, veuillez réessayer!"),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                      "Un problème est survenu, veuillez réessayer!"),
                                );
                              }
                          }
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

filter method in viewModel :

```
  List<AuditModel>? get myList => _searchString.isEmpty
      ? _auditList
      : _auditList!
          .where((element) =>
              element.title!
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.ordinalId.toString()!.toLowerCase() ==
                  (_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.title!
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.auditerName
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.perimName
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
                  convertDateTimeDisplay(element.datePlanification)
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()) ||
              element.status
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_searchString.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();

  void changeSearchString(String searchString) {
    _searchString = searchString;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

current behaviour : The filter is still applied when I leave the page and go back I want to be able to refresh the page when leave and go back
side note : am using a custom navbar as my main page and to navigate between pages :

````
  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();

  int index;
  int indexTab;

  BottomNavBar({required this.index, required this.indexTab});
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  PackageInfo _packageInfo = PackageInfo(
    appName: 'Unknown',
    packageName: 'Unknown',
    version: '1.13.20',
    buildNumber: 'Unknown',
  );

  int activeIndex = 0;
  bool isSelected0 = false;
  bool isSelected1 = false;
  bool isSelected2 = false;
  bool isSelected3 = false;
  bool isSelected = false;
  bool isAddPage = false;

  int changeActivePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      widget.index = index;
    });
    return index;
  }

  List<Widget> pages = [];
  List<int> listperims = [];

  final tabs = [
    "Mes Qrqc",
    "Profil",
    "Ajout Qrqc",
    "Notifications",
    "Liste des actions",
    "DMC",
    "Ajout action",
    "Audit"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages = [
      MainQrqcScreenWithTab(
        index: widget.indexTab,
      ),
      UserProfile(),
      AddQrqcScreen(),
      ListNotifications(),
      TasksMainView(
        index: 0,
      ),
      DmcDeep(),
      AddActionScreen(),
      AuditScreen()
    ];
    _initPackageInfo();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        if (message.notification != null) {
          debugPrint(message.notification!.body);
          debugPrint(message.notification!.title);
          notifAlert(context, message.notification!.title!,
              message.notification!.body!);
          print(message.notification!.body);
        }
      }
    });
    Provider.of<FirebaseProvider>(context, listen: false).subscribePerimTopic();
    Provider.of<FirebaseProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .subscribeUserIdTopic();

    super.initState();
  }

  fetchPerims() async {
    String clientId;
    listperims = (await UserViewModel().fetchUserperims());
    clientId = await SharedPreferenceToken().getClientId();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        listperims;
        if (clientId != "") {
          for (int perim in listperims) {
            FirebaseMessaging.instance
                .subscribeToTopic(clientId + "_" + perim.toString());
            print(clientId + "_" + perim.toString());
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      _packageInfo = info;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig.init(context);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.075),
          child: CustomBaseAppBar(
            title: tabs[widget.index],
            callback: () {
              setState(() {
                changeActivePage(3);
              });

              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
                  (value) => LocalNotificationsViewModel().readNotifications());
            },
            callback2: () {
              setState(() {
                changeActivePage(1);
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: widget.index == 2 || widget.index == 6
            ? Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: BottomAppBar(
                  clipBehavior:
                      Clip.antiAlias, //bottom navigation bar on scaffold
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //shape of notch
                  notchMargin: 6.0,

                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [kPrimaryColor, kPrimaryLightColor],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.topRight,
                          stops: [0.1, 0.8],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : BottomAppBar(
                clipBehavior:
                    Clip.antiAlias, //bottom navigation bar on scaffold
                color: Colors.transparent,
                shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //shape of notch
                notchMargin: 6.0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [kPrimaryColor, kPrimaryLightColor],
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.topRight,
                        stops: [0.1, 0.8],
                        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 9,
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    changeActivePage(0);
                                    setState(() {
                                      isSelected0 = !isSelected0;
                                      isSelected3 = !isSelected3;
                                      isSelected1 = false;
                                      isSelected2 = false;
                                      isSelected3 = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  color: !isAddPage && widget.index != 0
                                      ? !isSelected
                                          ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                          : Colors.white
                                      : isSelected0
                                          ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                          : Colors.white,
                                  icon: !isAddPage && widget.index != 0
                                      ? !isSelected
                                          ? Image.asset(
                                              'assets/icons/greyAllQrqc.png')
                                          : Image.asset(
                                              'assets/icons/allQrqc.png')
                                      : isSelected0
                                          ? Image.asset(
                                              'assets/icons/greyAllQrqc.png')
                                          : Image.asset(
                                              'assets/icons/allQrqc.png')),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Text("QRQC",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: !isAddPage && widget.index != 0
                                          ? !isSelected
                                              ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                              : Colors.white
                                          : isSelected0
                                              ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                              : Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 10)),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 38.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 9,
                                child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      changeActivePage(4);
                                      setState(() {
                                        isSelected1 = !isSelected1;
                                        isSelected0 = true;
                                        isSelected2 = false;
                                        isSelected3 = false;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    color: !isAddPage && widget.index == 4
                                        ? isSelected
                                            ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                            : Colors.white
                                        : !isSelected1
                                            ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                            : Colors.white,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.view_list_outlined)),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Text("Actions",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: !isAddPage && widget.index == 4
                                            ? isSelected
                                                ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                                : Colors.white
                                            : !isSelected1
                                                ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                                : Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 10)),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "v${_packageInfo.version}",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 9,
                                child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      changeActivePage(5);
                                      setState(() {
                                        isSelected2 = !isSelected2;
                                        isSelected0 = true;
                                        isSelected1 = false;
                                        isSelected3 = false;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    color: !isAddPage && widget.index == 5
                                        ? isSelected
                                            ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                            : Colors.white
                                        : !isSelected2
                                            ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                            : Colors.white,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.pie_chart_rounded)),
                              ),
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Text("DMC",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: !isAddPage && widget.index == 5
                                            ? isSelected
                                                ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                                : Colors.white
                                            : !isSelected2
                                                ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                                : Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 10)),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 9,
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    changeActivePage(7);
                                    setState(() {
                                      isSelected3 = !isSelected3;
                                      isSelected0 = true;
                                      isSelected1 = false;
                                      isSelected2 = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  color: !isAddPage && widget.index == 7
                                      ? isSelected
                                          ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                          : Colors.white
                                      : !isSelected3
                                          ? Colors.grey.shade400
                                          : Colors.white,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.download_done_rounded)),
                            ),
                            Flex```


if anyone knows how to fix this issue I'd be grateful
````

Comment: in your dispose() function, try adding a code that clears current filter. Or anywhere in the code, when you leave the page, try clearing filter before navigating to any other page.